# Sqoop import using control character as delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I want to ingest a table from SQLServer using Control character (\u0001) as my table contains almost all the delimiters available and I cannot use the remaining delimiters as it may arrive in the data in future. So I want to ingest it using control character.

Following is the structure of my sqoop command,

```
sqoop import --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --connect "my_connection_string" --username abc -P --query 'select * from xyz' --fields-terminated-by $'\u0001' --target-dir Path_In_HDFS --as-textfile -m 1
```

When I run the code I get below error,

```
Cannot understand character argument: \u0001
```

Also I want to create a table in hive to load this data using same delimiter. 
Kindly point out the correct way of doing it.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--fields-terminated-by '\001' could resolve your issue